# What are b and W on the parameter ratios update graphs in the dl4j UI Server?

Tags: deep-learning, deeplearning4j, dl4j

The labels I'm asking about are highlighted on the graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights and biases for the layer highlighted.